# Does a subcategory with right adjoint always have limit?

Tags: category-theory

Given a complete category $\mathsf{B}$ and its subcategory $\mathsf A$. If the inclusion functor $i:\mathsf A\to\mathsf B$ admits a right adjoint, is $\mathsf A$ necessarily complete?

Comment: In the case of a full subcategory, yes.

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, I knew that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very rare that assuming that a faithful functor is injective on objects gives you anything extra, because every faithful functor can be factored as a subcategory inclusion followed by an equivalence of categories. In particular, if the properties you are interested in are invariant under equivalence, then subcategory inclusions have the same properties as faithful functors.

With that in mind, it is easy to concoct a counterexample to your claim: just take any faithful left adjoint functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ is complete but $\mathcal{D}$ is not, and, if necessary, replace $\mathcal{D}$ so that $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ becomes a subcategory inclusion. Very concretely, you might take $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{Set}$, $\mathcal{D}$ to be the category of free groups, and $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ to be the free group functor.

Comment: So you mean the forgetful functor of the category of free groups is a counterexample? Very nice, thank you.